# My code does not return the proper coordinates for the cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, mouse-position

I am trying to write a program that needs to move a picture box to the coordinates of the cursor on a mouse down event in windows forms app C#.

```
private void MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //left mouse button pressed 
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                //gets the coords of the mouse
                MX = Control.MousePosition.X; 
                MY = Control.MousePosition.Y;
                //moves the picture box to these coords
                HitSlash.Left = MX;
                HitSlash.Top = MY;
                //shows the object, default hidden
                HitSlash.Show();
            }
        }
```

the program works however the picture box is always placed far down to the bottom right of the cursor. when i restart the program the picture box always has a different offset and cannot be fixed by manually changing the values of the coordinates.

Comment: When you start the program set the picturebox location to TOP = 0 and LEFT = 0.

Comment: Why don't you simply write `HitSlash.Location = e.Location; HitSlash.Show();`?

Answer (score 3):

The `Left` and `Right` properties are relative to the parent container, while `Control.MousePosition` is relative to the screen.
The [PointToClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient) method helps you converting screen coordinated to relative coordinates:

```
var mousePos = Control.MousePosition;
var coords = HitSlash.Parent.PointToClient(mousePos);
HitSlash.Left = coords.X;
HitSlash.Top = coords.Y;
```